# I do not understand very well what a PHP process is

Tags: php

I want to lock a file by `flock`. I read the documentation and it says that

> These locks only apply to the current PHP process.

So what is a `PHP process` ? If there is a PHP project inside a web server , and there are many clients opening the project on their computer's browser , are all these clients computers starting different PHP processes ? If so , does `flock` then really lock in that situation ? What I want is to lock a file on a webserver if I am the first accessing the file , even if there are many other clients computers trying to launch the same functionality on a page !

Comment: Each HTTP request through the webserver starts a new PHP instance for the page/script.

Comment: Maybe change the title? Somewhat like:"What is the definition of a php process?" or something?

Comment: I think the bigger question/isse is: "Does PHP always clean up flock [and any other open fds] even if the implementation does not start a new OS process?" It is easy to say (and I even did it) that each "PHP instance is fresh", but PHP does not need to start a new OS process.

Comment: Are you closing the lock? The lock is released also by fclose()

Comment: @user2864740 True, In particular mod_php with a threading MPM wouldn't fork a new process. (Just looking at it from the clean runtime point of view). I'd guess OP is really asking about flock behaviour on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on which os and how you have your server and php setup through the web server. On windows, I believe its one php.exe process which shouldn't be too difficult to grasp. On linux, one php process handles each apache request.

For example, I issued >

```
ps aux | grep php
```

I got:

```
root      4346  0.0  1.6 345920 19068 pts/0    T    Mar12   0:04 emacs mission_insert.php
```

this show that I opend a php file called mission_insert.php with emacs, which doesn't show anything about a php request but its handled through httpd/apache.

When I issue >

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

I get the following:

```
root      3255  0.0  2.3 616964 27720 ?        Ss   Mar11   0:22 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    7227  0.0  1.8 723060 22040 ?        S    03:35   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    7228  0.0  1.7 722828 20752 ?        S    03:35   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    7229  0.0  1.7 723500 20136 ?        S    03:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    7230  0.0  1.8 723008 22324 ?        S    03:35   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    7374  0.0  1.7 723136 20868 ?        S    09:38   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    7380  0.0  2.0 725124 23840 ?        S    09:38   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    7381  0.0  1.8 725140 21392 ?        S    09:38   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    7382  0.0  1.9 724620 22880 ?        S    09:38   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    7385  0.0  1.7 723028 20864 ?        S    09:38   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    7578  0.0  0.9 617232 11396 ?        S    10:22   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
root      7628  0.0  0.0 112640   960 pts/0    R+   11:27   0:00 grep --color=auto httpd
```